# Magento 2 - Filter on category

Tags: magento2, xml, filter

I want to do something like this to add a filter: http://demo-acm2.bird.eu/gear/bags.html

How and where to add that ? I've overrided `catalog_category_view.xml` to have a custom layout:

EDIT : to be more clear, I want to show ALL the layered-filter-block part, I have only "Wishlist" and "Compare", but I don't have the block on top of them (on the link it is called "Shopping Option")

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
            <container name="category.view.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="category-view" after="-">
                <!--<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.image" template="Magento_Catalog::category/image.phtml"/>-->
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.description" template="Magento_Catalog::category/description.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.cms" template="Magento_Catalog::category/cms.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.products" template="Magento_Catalog::category/products.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                    <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="category.product.type.details.renderers.default" as="default"/>
                    </block>
                    <!--<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">-->
                        <!--<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"-->
                               <!--name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"-->
                               <!--template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>-->
                    <!--</block>-->
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <!--<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>-->
                    </block>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                    </action>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="compareProductLink" xsi:type="string">.action.tocompare</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <!--<arguments>-->
                <!--<argument name="id" xsi:type="string">page-title-heading</argument>-->
                <!--<argument name="add_base_attribute_aria" xsi:type="string">page-title-heading toolbar-amount</argument>-->
            <!--</arguments>-->
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\Rss\Link" name="rss.link" template="Magento_Catalog::category/rss.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>

        <!--<referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>-->
        <!--<referenceBlock name="product_list_toolbar" remove="true"/>-->
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write code for it. Magento by default provides the option to show attributes under filters.

To do so:

- Go to **Stores** > **Attributes (Product)**.
- Click on existing attribute which you want to show under frontend filters.
- Change the value of **`Use in Layered Navigation`** from **No** to either **Filterable (with results)** or **Filterable (no results)**.
- Save the attribute and do the reindexing.

That's all.

Comment: I already have some product with Filterable. In my browser, on the left side I have only "Compare" and "Wishlist", I don't have any filter

Comment: @MorganTartreau, Have you followed the process mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Yes I have done that

Answer (score 0):

Solution : don't forget to add attributs to products, otherwise the filter layer won't showing